# how to create only deleted file instead of creating entire level under directory of sdcard in android

Tags: android

In sdcard of android device there is a directory with 3 levels of files each with different count of files, i can list all of them using

```
public void listDirectory(String dirPath, int level) {
    File dir = new File(dirPath);
    File[] firstLevelFiles = dir.listFiles();
    if (firstLevelFiles != null && firstLevelFiles.length > 0) {
        for (File aFile : firstLevelFiles) {
            for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
                System.out.print("\t");
            }
            if (aFile.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println("[" + aFile.getName() + "]");
                listDirectory(aFile.getAbsolutePath(), level + 1);
            } else {
                System.out.println(aFile.getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but i any file is deleted, i should create only deleted file, without disturbing the file structure.

Comment: You want to recreate deleted files? Is there a second directory you can compare which files were deleted? Android/Linux itself has no such thing as a wastebasket like e.g. Windows has. At least not with the standard configuration.

Comment: @jboi Thanks for reply, yes i need to recreate the deleted file and there is no another dir to compare.

Comment: In this case I have no idea, where you could get the deleted files from. As far as I know, Android (Linux) does not save this information anywhere. :-(

Comment: From bottom to top: (1) You can create and register a listener where ever you want. `onCreate` is probably a good place as it ensures, that the listener listens when the user can touch, click, ...

Comment: (2) If their buttons work and the layout of them is in `in_call_card` they must have called `setContentView` or `addView` or so somewhere. This would be the only way I can think of, to make the second layout work. Maybe, they have created the buttons programmatically and added it - and have not actually used the layout file? But to be honest, I'm guessing now. The only way to understand, what's really going on in the other code is, to inspect ALL of the code. This is beyond of what I can do here.

Comment: (3) What goes in the Activity: That would be a pretty standard activity with a layout - standard Android like described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html)